# Java Virtual Keyboard for Mac

Tags: java, macos

I'm working on an on-screen keyboard for Windows and macOS and I've made a little test app. It has a single button and types the letter “M” to the active application. It works for Windows 10, but not Mac (I'm running macOS 10.12). In macOS, as soon as I press the button, whichever app I'm trying to send the "M" to loses focus (the cursor for text entry disappears), even though my single button "keyboard" has setFocusable(false) all over the place. I tried my own MouseListener on the button too.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class main {
    private static Robot robot;
    private static Rectangle rectangle;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button button = new Button("M");
        button.setFocusable(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.add(button);

        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        //set everything I can think of to unfocusable!!!
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
        frame.getRootPane().setFocusable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendKeystroke();
            }
        });
        //Instead of adding a listener to the button, I've also tried my own MouseListener.
/*        button.addMouseListener(new MouseTrap());
        rectangle = button.getBounds();*/
    }

    private static void sendKeystroke(){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    }

    private static class MouseTrap extends MouseAdapter{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())){
                sendKeystroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like macOS does let some apps have focus without taking the cursor from another. e.g. VMware or spotlight search from the system tray.

[Cursor for VMware and IntelliJ at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du9UV.jpg)

I've seen other answer which are non-Java:

[Virtual Keyboard Cocoa & Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512106/how-to-create-virtual-keyboard-in-osx)

But do I really have to go all native when Java works on Windows? Apart from the learning curve (not done anything native on a Mac), I want to keep Win and Mac versions versions as close as possible.

Anyone know how I could get this working using straight Java?

(Note: As was the case with the questioner for the above link, I can't just use a keyboardview, as I want send modified/additional data from the keyboard e.g. text predictions. I believe that would require additional native code again.)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find the way very much. But it seems that it is not possible by pure Java without any native code.